# KeyCloak Authentication Flow with jumbojett/OpenID-Connect-PHP Library

Tags: php, openid, keycloak

I‘m struggling setting up a secured application with an OpenID provider.

What I have done:

- Set up KeyCloak Server
- Created simple php Application
- Loaded [jumbojett](https://github.com/jumbojett/OpenID-Connect-PHP) library
- Configured client

What am I doing:

- Try to access my application
- Get redirected to my KeyCloak instance
- Log in successfully
- Get redirected to my application

What the problem is:

The redirect url to my application contains some get parameters as code and so on. The problem is, when I refresh the page, I get an error message: the code can only be used once.

My question is, how can I provide a proper url, which the user can refresh?

Comment: Well redirect somewhere else then, after you processed the code … to a different URL, that does _not_ contain that parameter any more …?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But how can I ensure that the second url is not called directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some research and discovered that I didn't really understand the flow of authentication.

So after the user is redirected to my application, I had to store the Refresh Token in a Session Variable. Afterwards, I was able to redirect the user to the new page.

On the new page I had to check, if a Refresh Token has been stored and if it was valid. If so, I can show the user the content, otherwise, I have to redirect the user to the login page.